# How to define one function locally within another in my version of `reverse` -- getting parse errors

Tags: haskell

I have started studying Haskell, and I am try to write a "reverse" function.
I created 2 functions for that, and they work, but now I want to define one locally within the second, but I get syntax errors.  Here's what I'm doing:

```
let liste1 = [4,2,8,1,7,12]  
-- I create a random list

test(x,y)= if x==[] then y else test(tail(x),head(x):y) 
-- take a 2 list, with y=[] to have a list memory

inverse(x)=test(x,[]) 
-- and finally, to have only 1 parameter
```

and then, we have:

```
> inverse(liste1)
[12,7,1,8,2,4]
```

It's works! Amazing!

Now I want to have test as a **LOCAL** function.  This is what I have tried so far:

```
inverse(x) = let test(x,[]) in if x==[] then y else test(tail(x),head(x):y)
```

and

```
inverse(x) = let  if x==[] then y else test(tail(x),head(x):y) in test(x,[])
```

Both ways don't work, and I get the following error: `parse error on input ìn'`

I know it's basic question, and more basic solution, but I don't get it... Help me please!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I don't fully understand your question, do you want a reverse function that just takes one argument? What exactly is your problem?

Comment: i simply creat a reverse fonction, currently call test(x,y) BUT this fonction take 2 argument, with y need to be NULL list, and want crate a fonction, which need only one argument, the seconde, inverse(x)
but this one, depending of test(x,y)
and currently, i've 2 fonction test and inverse, and i want to have test locally on inverse

Comment: finaly, when all is done i want to have this respond
inverse([4,2,1]
>[1,2,4]
test([4,2,1],[])
>error test fonction doesn't exist ( because she is locally creat ON inverse

Comment: I suggest you drop the habit of putting parentheses around your argument lists. `inverse x` and `inverse(x)` are essentially the same, but `test x y` and `test(x,y)` are *very* different. Haskell doesn't use parentheses for defining parameter lists or for calling functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When adding definitions using `let`, you want to put your definition between `let` and `in`.

```hs
inverse(x) =
  let test(x,y) = if x==[] then y else test(tail(x),head(x):y) 
  in  test(x,[])
```

You could instead use `where` to give the definition afterwards:

```hs
inverse(x) = test(x,[])
  where test(x,y) = if x==[] then y else test(tail(x),head(x):y)
```

Comment: Thank you Will help me a lot !